# How to correct return View in Episerver plugin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I created Episerver plugin lib. In this library, I have a folder with Views. When I add a plugin to the Episerver project, I receive an error ("View not found"), maybe because of view located in another assembly. How to correct return View in Episerver plugin.

Now I fixed it that way:

```
return View("~/bin/Views/Temp/Index.cshtml", model);
```

Comment: Did you place the plugin in the modules folder?

Comment: It is possible to include Razor views in addons. Have a look at `Paths.ToResource(typeInModuleAssembly, moduleRelativeResourcePath)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to duplicate your work and also put views under /Views in your web project (where all page types views resides) so in your cases Views/Temp/Index.cshtml